# Invoke MS Office applications such as Word, Excel, PowerPoint in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: firefox, web-applications, plugins, ms-office

I need to use WebDav to edit remote MS Office documents in local Word/Excel/PowerPoint app. The documents reside on a WebDav-enable non-SharePoint server.

I found Microsoft’s Office Web Apps Browser Plugin for Firefox allow to edit Office documents on skydrive.live.com. My question is that whether this plugin have to work with an Office Web Apps-capable server, such as SharePoint 2010? Can it work with a WebDav-enable non-SharePoint server?

Any API documentation for using this plugin?

Comment: The answer below has the info you need. But to answer your question: the user only needs to have Office 2010 installed on their computer for the plugin to work. Then you need to instantiate the plugin as an object and call those API methods (in the link below) on it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for the question is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407576

Basically, we can use FFWinPlugin Plug-in whose implementation is defined in **NPSPWRAP.dll**, a dynamic link-library provided by Microsoft’s Office Web Apps Browser Plugin. All you need to do is to define an object in the server's response, like below:

```
<object id="winFirefoxPlugin" type="application/x-sharepoint" width="0" height="0" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

Create a simple javascript code, to obtain the above object, which is implicitly processed by the Office Web Apps browser plugin to give you a FFWinPlugin object. All you need to do is to call appropriate **EditDocument** methods of this object for editing.

Comment: "Create a simple javascript code, to obtain the above object" -- Would you explain how to get a reference to the object using javascript, so we can use the API you linked to?

Comment: TIL you can call the API methods directly on the object after getting it with `document.getElementById("winFirefoxPlugin")`